# MySQL causing major I/O Lag

Tags: centos, mysql, innodb, roundcube, plesk

I have a mysql server (version 5.1) running Roundcube Webmail client on a plesk box (onyx). We have a few hundred users on it during the day. My hypervisor, Virtuozzo, they have been working with us on this all day and found that the container itself is generating an enormous amount of I/O.

> The I/O got so high that it crashed the entire server, with corruption
>   to the file system.

**

> DISCLAIMER: The SHOW anything below is fresh after a mysql stop/start!

**

(On Centos 6.9)

Specs:

```
AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6344

Core Name
Abu Dhabi
# of Cores
12-Core
# of Threads
12
Operating Frequency
2.6 GHz
Hyper Transports
6.40 GT/s
L2 Cache
6 x 2MB
L3 Cache
2 x 8MB
Manufacturing Tech
32 nm

30GB RAM (I have provided this to the container), server has 64 total.
```

My my.cnf config is as follows: (and sorry, it is messy, a lot of us have been trying to keep the server up all day. You may organize it if you wish to do so..)

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_table_locks=0
#innodb_buffer_pool_size=10240M


#Add
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G
thread_cache_size=20
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=32M
innodb_file_io_threads=8
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_thread_concurrency=24


# Recommended. Also changed thread concurrency to 24 from 12
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

key_buffer_size=64M

slow_query_log=1 
slow_query_log_file=mysql-slow.log 
long_query_time = 1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2

[mysqld]
max_connections=2000
max_user_connections=0
```

More Info:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
+----------------------+---------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| innodb_log_file_size | 5242880 |
+----------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

More Info:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Aborted_clients                   | 0        |
| Aborted_connects                  | 1        |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use             | 0        |
| Binlog_cache_use                  | 0        |
| Bytes_received                    | 830216   |
| Bytes_sent                        | 39213368 |
| Com_admin_commands                | 5        |
| Com_assign_to_keycache            | 0        |
| Com_alter_db                      | 0        |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade              | 0        |
| Com_alter_event                   | 0        |
| Com_alter_function                | 0        |
| Com_alter_procedure               | 0        |
| Com_alter_server                  | 0        |
| Com_alter_table                   | 0        |
| Com_alter_tablespace              | 0        |
| Com_analyze                       | 0        |
| Com_backup_table                  | 0        |
| Com_begin                         | 0        |
| Com_binlog                        | 0        |
| Com_call_procedure                | 0        |
| Com_change_db                     | 2        |
| Com_change_master                 | 0        |
| Com_check                         | 0        |
| Com_checksum                      | 0        |
| Com_commit                        | 0        |
| Com_create_db                     | 0        |
| Com_create_event                  | 0        |
| Com_create_function               | 0        |
| Com_create_index                  | 0        |
| Com_create_procedure              | 0        |
| Com_create_server                 | 0        |
| Com_create_table                  | 0        |
| Com_create_trigger                | 0        |
| Com_create_udf                    | 0        |
| Com_create_user                   | 0        |
| Com_create_view                   | 0        |
| Com_dealloc_sql                   | 0        |
| Com_delete                        | 22       |
| Com_delete_multi                  | 0        |
| Com_do                            | 0        |
| Com_drop_db                       | 0        |
| Com_drop_event                    | 0        |
| Com_drop_function                 | 0        |
| Com_drop_index                    | 0        |
| Com_drop_procedure                | 0        |
| Com_drop_server                   | 0        |
| Com_drop_table                    | 0        |
| Com_drop_trigger                  | 0        |
| Com_drop_user                     | 0        |
| Com_drop_view                     | 0        |
| Com_empty_query                   | 0        |
| Com_execute_sql                   | 0        |
| Com_flush                         | 0        |
| Com_grant                         | 0        |
| Com_ha_close                      | 0        |
| Com_ha_open                       | 0        |
| Com_ha_read                       | 0        |
| Com_help                          | 0        |
| Com_insert                        | 7        |
| Com_insert_select                 | 0        |
| Com_install_plugin                | 0        |
| Com_kill                          | 0        |
| Com_load                          | 0        |
| Com_load_master_data              | 0        |
| Com_load_master_table             | 0        |
| Com_lock_tables                   | 0        |
| Com_optimize                      | 0        |
| Com_preload_keys                  | 0        |
| Com_prepare_sql                   | 0        |
| Com_purge                         | 0        |
| Com_purge_before_date             | 0        |
| Com_release_savepoint             | 0        |
| Com_rename_table                  | 0        |
| Com_rename_user                   | 0        |
| Com_repair                        | 0        |
| Com_replace                       | 0        |
| Com_replace_select                | 0        |
| Com_reset                         | 0        |
| Com_restore_table                 | 0        |
| Com_revoke                        | 0        |
| Com_revoke_all                    | 0        |
| Com_rollback                      | 0        |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint         | 0        |
| Com_savepoint                     | 0        |
| Com_select                        | 4259     |
| Com_set_option                    | 1098     |
| Com_show_authors                  | 0        |
| Com_show_binlog_events            | 0        |
| Com_show_binlogs                  | 0        |
| Com_show_charsets                 | 0        |
| Com_show_collations               | 1        |
| Com_show_column_types             | 0        |
| Com_show_contributors             | 0        |
| Com_show_create_db                | 0        |
| Com_show_create_event             | 0        |
| Com_show_create_func              | 0        |
| Com_show_create_proc              | 0        |
| Com_show_create_table             | 0        |
| Com_show_create_trigger           | 0        |
| Com_show_databases                | 3        |
| Com_show_engine_logs              | 0        |
| Com_show_engine_mutex             | 0        |
| Com_show_engine_status            | 0        |
| Com_show_events                   | 0        |
| Com_show_errors                   | 0        |
| Com_show_fields                   | 449      |
| Com_show_function_status          | 0        |
| Com_show_grants                   | 0        |
| Com_show_keys                     | 0        |
| Com_show_master_status            | 0        |
| Com_show_new_master               | 0        |
| Com_show_open_tables              | 0        |
| Com_show_plugins                  | 0        |
| Com_show_privileges               | 0        |
| Com_show_procedure_status         | 0        |
| Com_show_processlist              | 0        |
| Com_show_profile                  | 0        |
| Com_show_profiles                 | 0        |
| Com_show_slave_hosts              | 0        |
| Com_show_slave_status             | 0        |
| Com_show_status                   | 7        |
| Com_show_storage_engines          | 0        |
| Com_show_table_status             | 0        |
| Com_show_tables                   | 3        |
| Com_show_triggers                 | 0        |
| Com_show_variables                | 9        |
| Com_show_warnings                 | 0        |
| Com_slave_start                   | 0        |
| Com_slave_stop                    | 0        |
| Com_stmt_close                    | 0        |
| Com_stmt_execute                  | 0        |
| Com_stmt_fetch                    | 0        |
| Com_stmt_prepare                  | 0        |
| Com_stmt_reprepare                | 0        |
| Com_stmt_reset                    | 0        |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data           | 0        |
| Com_truncate                      | 0        |
| Com_uninstall_plugin              | 0        |
| Com_unlock_tables                 | 0        |
| Com_update                        | 26       |
| Com_update_multi                  | 0        |
| Com_xa_commit                     | 0        |
| Com_xa_end                        | 0        |
| Com_xa_prepare                    | 0        |
| Com_xa_recover                    | 0        |
| Com_xa_rollback                   | 0        |
| Com_xa_start                      | 0        |
| Compression                       | OFF      |
| Connections                       | 1167     |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables           | 16       |
| Created_tmp_files                 | 5        |
| Created_tmp_tables                | 39       |
| Delayed_errors                    | 0        |
| Delayed_insert_threads            | 0        |
| Delayed_writes                    | 0        |
| Flush_commands                    | 1        |
| Handler_commit                    | 4309     |
| Handler_delete                    | 2        |
| Handler_discover                  | 0        |
| Handler_prepare                   | 0        |
| Handler_read_first                | 17       |
| Handler_read_key                  | 6473     |
| Handler_read_next                 | 26911    |
| Handler_read_prev                 | 0        |
| Handler_read_rnd                  | 1449     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next             | 3241     |
| Handler_rollback                  | 0        |
| Handler_savepoint                 | 0        |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback        | 0        |
| Handler_update                    | 24       |
| Handler_write                     | 2468     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data     | 3675     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty    | 0        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed  | 239      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free     | 1044849  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc     | 52       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total    | 1048576  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd | 5        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_seq | 0        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests  | 125478   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads          | 3403     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free      | 0        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests | 545      |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                | 156      |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs        | 0        |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads         | 0        |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes        | 0        |
| Innodb_data_read                  | 62099456 |
| Innodb_data_reads                 | 3447     |
| Innodb_data_writes                | 321      |
| Innodb_data_written               | 8141824  |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written        | 239      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes               | 38       |
| Innodb_log_waits                  | 0        |
| Innodb_log_write_requests         | 575      |
| Innodb_log_writes                 | 53       |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs              | 80       |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs      | 0        |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes      | 0        |
| Innodb_os_log_written             | 296448   |
| Innodb_page_size                  | 16384    |
| Innodb_pages_created              | 18       |
| Innodb_pages_read                 | 3657     |
| Innodb_pages_written              | 239      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits     | 0        |
| Innodb_row_lock_time              | 0        |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg          | 0        |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max          | 0        |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits             | 0        |
| Innodb_rows_deleted               | 2        |
| Innodb_rows_inserted              | 7        |
| Innodb_rows_read                  | 32244    |
| Innodb_rows_updated               | 24       |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed            | 0        |
| Key_blocks_unused                 | 53585    |
| Key_blocks_used                   | 3        |
| Key_read_requests                 | 6        |
| Key_reads                         | 3        |
| Key_write_requests                | 0        |
| Key_writes                        | 0        |
| Last_query_cost                   | 0.000000 |
| Max_used_connections              | 16       |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows          | 0        |
| Open_files                        | 3        |
| Open_streams                      | 0        |
| Open_table_definitions            | 241      |
| Open_tables                       | 64       |
| Opened_files                      | 365      |
| Opened_table_definitions          | 241      |
| Opened_tables                     | 519      |
| Prepared_stmt_count               | 0        |
| Qcache_free_blocks                | 0        |
| Qcache_free_memory                | 0        |
| Qcache_hits                       | 0        |
| Qcache_inserts                    | 0        |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes              | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached                 | 0        |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache           | 0        |
| Qcache_total_blocks               | 0        |
| Queries                           | 7047     |
| Questions                         | 7047     |
| Rpl_status                        | NULL     |
| Select_full_join                  | 0        |
| Select_full_range_join            | 0        |
| Select_range                      | 995      |
| Select_range_check                | 0        |
| Select_scan                       | 44       |
| Slave_open_temp_tables            | 0        |
| Slave_retried_transactions        | 0        |
| Slave_running                     | OFF      |
| Slow_launch_threads               | 0        |
| Slow_queries                      | 31       |
| Sort_merge_passes                 | 0        |
| Sort_range                        | 31       |
| Sort_rows                         | 1449     |
| Sort_scan                         | 0        |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates           | 0        |
| Ssl_accepts                       | 0        |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits           | 0        |
| Ssl_cipher                        |          |
| Ssl_cipher_list                   |          |
| Ssl_client_connects               | 0        |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates          | 0        |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth              | 0        |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode               | 0        |
| Ssl_default_timeout               | 0        |
| Ssl_finished_accepts              | 0        |
| Ssl_finished_connects             | 0        |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits            | 0        |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses          | 0        |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode            | NONE     |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows       | 0        |
| Ssl_session_cache_size            | 0        |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts        | 0        |
| Ssl_sessions_reused               | 0        |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries    | 0        |
| Ssl_verify_depth                  | 0        |
| Ssl_verify_mode                   | 0        |
| Ssl_version                       |          |
| Table_locks_immediate             | 4331     |
| Table_locks_waited                | 0        |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used             | 0        |
| Tc_log_page_size                  | 0        |
| Tc_log_page_waits                 | 0        |
| Threads_cached                    | 12       |
| Threads_connected                 | 4        |
| Threads_created                   | 16       |
| Threads_running                   | 1        |
| Uptime                            | 405      |
| Uptime_since_flush_status         | 405      |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
291 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And my [GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/fA9bjdJM) are here

I am not sure why, but I am getting MAJOR I/O to my hypervisor from this container. Here is some info from newrelic:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I understand that MYSQLTuner needs to have the mysql service be running during this issue times but we made changes to the my.cnf file and restarted, and then ran it. Here is some additional information running right after a fresh service stop/start so keep in mind this may not be helpful:

[image]

**EDIT:**

After running the server for a few hours, here is mysqltuner output:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Again everyone - I am not a database pro so please go easy on me :)

So my question is how can I resolve this extremely bad slowdown I have. I am at a loss for where to begin.. If you need additional info from me let me know. Thank you all!

Comment: Having a disabled query cache and thread cache are immediate problems you can take care of now.

Comment: Michael nice to see you again! Can you suggest a size?

Comment: The script itself should have given you recommendations for them.

Comment: Michael, I just ran the script again did not say anything about that. See here: https://cl.ly/0m1K3t1i1B2d https://cl.ly/3g3d3U1F0B0V https://cl.ly/1X0W1M44251j

Comment: Also Michael, sorry I am not a database pro, would you mind posting an answer of your suggestion that would be super helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Hmm. I don't mind looking at images, if it's really necessary, but please upload them here. That site only gives me "Oops! Surprised?" Better still to copy and paste text whenever possible.

Comment: Ok I will upload them sorry

Comment: Your highest number of simultaneous connections is 16 of 151, so I guess I'd start with 16 for the thread_cache_size, and adjust it upward if necessary later.

Comment: I have thread_cache_size = 20 already (sorry for confusing my.cnf...)

Comment: Yes, but your running copy of MySQL doesn't appear to be using that configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74960/discussion-between-gordon-snappleweed-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: What do you suggest for query_cache_size ? Can you post an answer with your total recommendation?

Comment: Hi @GordonSnappleweed, you're aware that you're running a 10-year-old version of MySQL?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history

Comment: I'm looking at your newrelic stats.  The "MAJOR I/O", is that the 50.000 bytes written to the redo logs, or the 10 innodb page operations per second?

Comment: @gordonsnappleweed Still need entire TEXT of mysqltuner report. Also, A) complete error.log B) ulimit -a C) iostat -x (when your test is running for extended IOPS information. Is there any good reason for running 5.1.73 version of MySQL? 5.6 and 5.7 have been successful in production for many months and have been significantly improved..

Comment: @gordonsnappleweed  Pick up this script from   https://pastebin.com/aZAu2zZ0  for MySQL to quickly determine Global Status resources used/released for period of time you control in the script with SLEEP.  And post your complete TEXT mysqltuner report, please.